# Java reading Strings from file ant putting them into a multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, readfile

Basically, i have a bunch of info, that i need to read from a file and put it into a 2D array. 
The data.txt file looks like this:

```
a 2016-10-03 Boston Type1 112
b 2016-05-02 Chicago Type2 150
c 2016-06-01 Denver Type3 1500
d 2016-08-26 NewYork Type4 80
```

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of requirements, not a lot of effort, nor a question. Please read the help center to understand how to ask a question and what our expectations are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you obviously require is a 2D Array which will ultimately consist of unlimited rows with 5 columns per row. To declare your 2D Array you will first need to decide what data type you would like each column to be. For example, let's take a look at the first line of your file contents:

**a 2016-10-03 Boston Type1 112**

1st we have '**a**' which is a String data type;

2nd we have '**2016-10-03**' which is a Date data type,

3rd we have '**Boston**' which again is a String data type,

4th we have '**Type1**' which is yet again a String data type,

5th and finally we have '**112**' which is most likely a Integer data type.

If you want to maintain these particular data types within you 2D Array then you will want to declare your array as Object:

**Object[][] myArray = {};**

If you would prefer to just maintain these data types as string which is what they truely are within the text file then you will want to declare your 2D array as String:

**String[][] myArray = {};**

This is up to you and how you decide should be based on how you will deal with the elemental data as it is retrieved from the array.

You will first need to determine how many rows you will need to dimension your array. To do this you will need to know how many data lines are contained within the data file. To do this we need to make a simple method so to acquire this amount. Let's create a method to count the number of text lines within a text file, we'll call it **countFileLines()**:

```
private static int countFileLines(String filePath) {
    try {
        int count = 0;
        try (InputStream inSt = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath))) {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean NoNewLine = false;
            while ((readChars = inSt.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') { ++count; }
                }
                NoNewLine = (c[readChars - 1] != '\n');
            }   
            if(NoNewLine) { ++count; }
            inSt.close();
        }
        return count;
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("countFileLines() Method ERROR - File Not Found!");
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("countFileLines() Method ERROR - IO Exception Encountered\n" + ex.getMessage());
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Now that we have that out of the way let's start with a Two Dimensional 'String' Array:

```
// Let's get the number of data lines within file.
// If file is not in classpath then supply full path.
int dl = countFileLines("data.txt");
if (dl == 0) { System.exit(0); }
String[][] myArray = new String[dl][5];
```

There, now we've declared and initialized our 2D String Array to hold the total number of rows as what is contain for data lines within the supplied data file and we've set the columns to five since we already know that each file line consists of 5 string chunks of data delimited with a space.

Now all we need do is to read in each data file line (row) and place each string chunk (column) into their respective element within the 2D String Array. We'll need to make a simple custom method to carry out the task. Let's call it **applyFileDataToArray()**:

```
private static String[][] applyFileDataToArray(String filePath, String[][] myArray) {
    // declare and intialize a String variable to hold string 
    // data lines read from file.
    String line = "";
    // Declare and initialize a temporary 2D Array to fill with file data
    // and return.
    String[][] tmpArray = new String[myArray.length][myArray[0].length];
    // Declare and iniialize a Integer variable to be used as a incremental
    // index counter for our temporary 2D Array.
    int cnt = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        // Read in each line of the data text file so as to place each
        // line of data into the a temporary 2D String Array which will
        // be ulimately returned...
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            // Skip past blank lines in the text file and only process file lines
            // which actually contain data.
            if (!line.equals("")) { 
                // Each line of data within the data text file consists
                // of a string with 5 data chunks each delimited with a 
                // whitespace. We place each data chunk into a String 
                // Array and then interate through this array and place 
                // each element into the 2D Array.
                String[] tok = line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; i++) {
                    tmpArray[cnt][i] = tok[i];
                }
                // increment index counter...
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        // Data now acquired from file - Close the BufferReader
        br.close();
    } 
    // Trap IO Exceptions from the Bufferreader if any...
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("\n\u001B[31mThe supplied data file could"
                         + " not be found!\n\u001B[39;49m" + filePath);
    }
    // Return filled 2D Array
    return tmpArray;
}
```

The method above is well commented so it should be relatively easy to understand what is going on there.

So now with your two new methods in place our 'main' code should look something like this:

```
int dl = CountFileLines("data.txt");
if (dl == 0) { System.exit(0); }
String[][] myArray = new String[dl][5];
myArray = applyFileDataToArray("data.txt", myArray);

// Display the contents of our 2D Array to Console...
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nROW " + (i+1) + ":");
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.println("\tColumn " + (j+1) + ":  " + myArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, if you want to maintain specific data types within the elemental columns of your 2D Array then you will need to declare and initialize your 2D Array as a Object type. Your ' main' code would then look like:

```
int dl = CountFileLines("data.txt");
if (dl == 0) { System.exit(0); }
Object[][] myArray = new Object[dl][5];
myArray = applyFileDataToArray("data.txt", myArray);

// Display the contents of our 2D Array to Console...
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("\nROW " + (i+1) + ":");
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        System.out.println("\tColumn " + (j+1) + ":  " + myArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

and our **applyFileDataToArray()** method would be a wee bit different so as to accommodate the differently required data types. The method would now look like:

```
private static Object[][] applyFileDataToArray(String filePath, Object[][] myArray) {
    String line = "";
    Object[][] tmpArray = new Object[myArray.length][myArray[0].length];
    int cnt = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        // Read in each line of the data text file so as to place each
        // line of data into the a temporary 2D Object Array which will
        // be ulimately returned...
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            // Skip past blank lines in the text file and only process file lines
            // which actually contain data.
            if (!line.equals("")) { 
                // Each line of data within the data text file consists
                // of a string with 5 data chunks each delimited with a 
                // whitespace. We place each data chunk into a String 
                // Array and then interate through this array and place 
                // each element into the 2D Object Array with their respective
                // data type.
                String[] tok = line.split(" ");
                tmpArray[cnt][0] = tok[0];
                tmpArray[cnt][1] = cDate(tok[1], "yyyy-MM-dd");
                tmpArray[cnt][2] = tok[2];
                tmpArray[cnt][3] = tok[3];
                tmpArray[cnt][4] = Integer.valueOf(tok[4]);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        // Close the BufferReader
        br.close();
    } 
    // Trap IO Exceptions from the Bufferreader if any...
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("\n\u001B[31mThe supplied Translation Table file could"
                         + " not be found!\n\u001B[39;49m" + filePath);
    }
    // Return filled 2D Object Array
    return tmpArray;
}
```

Notice the line: **tmpArray[cnt][1] = CDate(tok[1], "YYYY-MM-dd");** within the above code. This line contains yet another custom method to convert a date string to a Date data type. Here is the code for the **cDate()** method:

```
private static Date cDate(String val, String... expectedFormat) {
    //Usage:  Date d = cDate("2016-06-22", "yyyy-MM-dd");

    String dFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    if (expectedFormat.length != 0) { dFormat = expectedFormat[0]; }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try { 
        Date bdate = formatter.parse(val);
        return bdate;   // Default format is 01/01/2015
    }
    catch (ParseException e) { return null; }
}
```

Hope this helps you (and others).

Comment: Thanks for you comment DevilsHnd, its really thorough and easy to understand. I'll try to implement all of this in my program, when i get back home. You're THE MAN!